# Что не так с массивом javascript?

Tags: массивы, json

Получаю данные с стороннего API в виде строки ( по  websocket):

````
```ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
let messageGateObj = JSON.parse(evt.data);
console.log('Array.isArray(messageGateObj.params) ', Array.isArray(messageGateObj.params));
let toString = {}.toString;
console.log('toString.call(messageGateObj.params)=', toString.call(messageGateObj.params)); // 
[object Array]
}```
````

Меня интересует messageGateObj.params
его структура при выводе:

````
[false,
{ asks: [ [Array], [Array] ], bids: [ [Array], [Array], [Array] ] },
'XRP_USDT'
]```

двумя способами проверил, что это является массив. Но методы массивов не работают на нем: length,splice

1) messageGateObj.params.length
2) messageGateObj.params.splice
3) messageGateObj.params[0]

Выдает "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

Наверное я что-то не замечаю. Что не так подскажите.

Вот полный код в нем ошибки:
```ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
  console.log('typeof evt.data:', typeof evt.data);
  let messageGateObj = JSON.parse(evt.data);
  console.log('Array.isArray(messageGateObj.params) ', Array.isArray(messageGateObj.params));
  console.log('messageGateObj.params', messageGateObj.params);
  console.log('messageGateObj:', messageGateObj);
  // console.log('messageGateObj.params.length', messageGateObj.params.length); // ошибка Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  console.log('messageGateObj.params.constructor.name === Array', messageGateObj.params.constructor.name === 'Array');  // ошибка Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
  let toString = {}.toString;
  console.log('toString.call(messageGateObj.params)=', toString.call(messageGateObj.params)); // [object Array]
};```

В консоли выводится:
    `typeof evt.data: string
    Array.isArray(messageGateObj.params)  false
    messageGateObj.params undefined
    messageGateObj: { error: null, result: { status: 'success' }, id: 974 
    }
    C:\nodejs\server\Current\gate\gatecurent\nodejs\lib\gate.js:130
      console.log('messageGateObj.params.constructor.name === Array', 
    messageGateObj.params.constructor.name === 'Array');  // ошибка 
    Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined`
````

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Что "это"? Приведите нормальный пример данных.

Comment: Хм, ну и где тут `params` в `messageGateObj`? - `messageGateObj.params undefined`

Comment: по ходу я понял. этот код выполняется при каждом получении сообщение по websocket. А в первом сообщении действительно нет этих данных messageGateObj.params, но в последующих сообщениях эти данные присутствуют

Comment: Проверяйте `if (messageGateObj.params) { ... }`. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Да сам это уже сделал. Огромное спасибо. Как обычно и бывает- невнимательность. Огромное спасибо !!!

Answer (score 2):

Вы не замечаете, что у объекта `messageGateObj` нет свойства `params`.

Непосредственно перед обращением к `messageGateObj.params.length` выведите

```
console.log(messageGateObj);
```

Ваш `let messageGateObj` внутри анонимной функции `function (evt) { ... }` - локальная переменная. Снаружи этой функции Вы обращаетесь к какому-то другому объекту.

```js
let messageGateObj = {
  method: 'depth.update',
  params: [ false, { asks: [Array], bids: [Array] }, 'XRP_USDT' ],
  id: null 
};
console.log(messageGateObj.params.length);
```

Comment: Оно есть. Я просто его не показал:
 `console.log('messageGateObj.params', messageGateObj.params); //выводит`
Вот :
``` console.log('messageGateObj:', messageGateObj);```

Comment: @Illusion Вам же хуже. Его нет.

Comment: Вот :
``` console.log('messageGateObj:', messageGateObj);``` выводит : `messageGateObj: {
  method: 'depth.update',
  params: [ false, { asks: [Array], bids: [Array] }, 'XRP_USDT' ],
  id: null
}`

Comment: @Illusion Ваш `let messageGateObj` внутри анонимной функции `function (evt) { ... }` - локальная переменная.

Comment: весь код находится внутри этой функции function (evt) { ... }

Comment: @Illusion Нет, не находится.

Comment: То есть я могу вывести данные с этого объекта,  могу определить что в нем есть массив, но методы массива применить к нему не могу?

Comment: @Illusion Вы можете привести в вопросе полный код, в которoм возникает ошибка, или нет?

Comment: Совсем  запутался. Я получаю строку, преобразую ее в объект. В объекте есть массив и  функции массива к  массиву внутри объекта не работают. Что не так?

Comment: @Illusion Вы можете привести в вопросе полный код, в которoм возникает ошибка, или нет?

Comment: Вывел в самом конце

Comment: @Illusion Добавьте то, что выводится в консоль.

Comment: Добавил вывод консоли. по ходу я понял. этот код выполняется при каждом получении сообщение по  websocket. А в первом сообщении действительно нет этих данных messageGateObj.params, но в последующих сообщениях эти данные присутствуют.